# Python plot points on the same scatter plot using a for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of objects. I want to plot two particular attributes from each of these objects on to a scatter plot. I want to do this WITHOUT creating a list of x and y data points before plotting.

I tried the following but it plots a new graph for each data point instead(somehow the datapoint isn't visible either):

```py
for i in config:
    plt.scatter(i.timestep, i.totalCalcAtoms)
    plt.pause(0.05)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Try `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and `ax.scatter()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the change suggested by @Ynjxsjmh worked. The following was the finally used code:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.title(f'cutoff(Angstron)={cutoff}')
for i in config:
    ax.scatter(i.timestep, i.totalCalcAtoms,color="blue")
    ax.scatter(i.timestep, i.proton_count,color="red")

plt.show()
```

Comment: I ran your original code and everything went fine, a single plot… so it was a different, probably non-recurrent problem.  Anyway, now it works for you too…

Comment: @gboffi I was running it in a jupyter notebook. Can that be any different?

Comment: I was running it in the terminal, probably the notebook was the reason